# How to get replace value of column with its matching foreign key in another table?

Tags: mysql

So I have two tables. One is client that looks like this

```
+----------+-----------+----------+-------------+--------+---------+---------+----------------+------------+-------+---------+
| ClientId | FirstName | LastName | DateOfBirth | Gender | PriLang | SecLang | Address        | City       | State | ZipCode |
+----------+-----------+----------+-------------+--------+---------+---------+----------------+------------+-------+---------+
|    00002 | Peter     | Parker   | 2001-08-10  | Male   |       4 |       1 | 2389 Some Road | Where City | MA    | 60042   |
+----------+-----------+----------+-------------+--------+---------+---------+----------------+------------+-------+---------+
```

And the other is language

```
+-------------------+-----------------+
| LanguageId        | LanguageName    |
+-------------------+-----------------+
|                 1 | English         |
|                 2 | Spanish         |
|                 3 | Vietnamese      |
|                 4 | French          |
|                 5 | Korean          |
|                 6 | Japanese        |
|                 7 | Italian         |
+-------------------+-----------------+
```

I cannot figure out how to replace the foreign key values in PriLang and SecLang with the Language names from the language table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join the language table twice

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
`ClientId`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `DateOfBirth`, `Gender`
, l1.LanguageName 'PriLang', l2.LanguageName 'SecLang', `Address`, `City`, `State`, `ZipCode`
FROM client c
INNER JOIN 
language l1 ON c.PriLang = l1.LanguageId
INNER JOIN 
language l2 ON c.SecLang = l2.LanguageId;

| ClientId | FirstName | LastName | DateOfBirth | Gender | Address        | City       | State | ZipCode | PriLang | SecLang |
| -------- | --------- | -------- | ----------- | ------ | -------------- | ---------- | ----- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
| 2        | Peter     | Parker   | 2001-08-10  | Male   | 2389 Some Road | Where City | MA    | 60042   | French  | English |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/4)

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly in terminal but for some reason when I query from frontend, it sends the column name as the original from the language table and since theres 2, the second language overwrites the first one. So instead of PriLang = French | SecLang = English, I only get LanguageName = English.

Comment: I changed the code a little, see it that works better. Else you must create a new question with your code you use.

Comment: Still the same but thanks anyways. I can try to figure it out.